# Linq select one occurrence

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, visual-studio-2012

how can I use link to fetch one-to-one relation that does not contain duplicates? Example:

**ID** |  **STATUS**

1 |   CHECKIN

2 |   CHECKOUT

2 |   CHECKOUT

1    |   CHECKIN

**3   |    CHECKOUT** <--

I should only retrieve the **ID 3 CHECKOUT**  because he is not duplicated.

Can you help me using linq?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a Group and ask for only group items that = 1

```
Dim nonDuplicates = (From x In query Group By x.Id, x.Status Into grp = Group 
                     Where grp.Count = 1)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to group by both fields?

Comment: Thank you very much, @OneFineDay!

Answer (score 0):

The other answer will still retrieve all the duplicated items, just removing duplicates of them. If you want to *only* retrieve non-duplicated items, as you stated in your original question, this will work for you:

```
Item singles = items.Where(i => !items.Any(j => !i.Equals(j) && i.id == j.id));
```